# Product List collection sort order

Tags: magento2

How to display list page collection by alphabetical order in list page in magento 2?I have check that list collection comes from layer.php in magento.How to display collection in alphabetical order in list page.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this globally from

> Stores -> COnfiguration -> Catalog -> Storefront -> Product Listing
>   Sort by

Selecting Product name.
[image]

Also from category edit page. Select catagory from **Catalog -> Categories**

> Display Settings -> Default Product Listing Sort By

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.but i want name in descending order, i need to display products starts with  z first.